# SuiteScript 2.0 record.setCurrentSublistValue issue with filtered fields

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a scenario where I'm copying a custom record (body) with a custom child record (lines).

On the sublist, there is a `commodity` field, followed by a `costitem` field. Both are list/record types.

The cost item list/record has a `commodity` field on it which is filtered in the sublist, so we can only enter a cost item where the `commodity` value matches.

[image]

The body record is created as dynamic.

The `commodity` field is set on the sublist BEFORE the cost item field, and I have validated the `costitem` I'm setting DOES have the correct matching `commodity` value. (simulated by entering the data manually in the UI).

However, I'm getting an invalid field ref for `costitem`.

When I remove the filter from the `costitem` field definition, it works a charm.

The question therefore, is how do we set a sublistvalue when there is another field which must be set first.

The code I'm currently using:

```
        var sourceLineCount = sourceRec.getLineCount({sublistId:'recmachcustrecordcpqx_line_parent'});
        var lineFields = ['custrecordcpqx_commodity','custrecordcpqx_costitem'];

        for (var sourceLine = 0; sourceLine < sourceLineCount; sourceLine++) {
            newLineRecord.selectNewLine({sublistId:'recmachcustrecordcpqx_line_parent'});
            lineFields.forEach(function(field){
                newLineRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'recmachcustrecordcpqx_line_parent',
                    fieldId: field, 
                    value: sourceRec.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'recmachcustrecordcpqx_line_parent',
                        fieldId: field,
                        line: sourceLine,
                        }), 
                });
            });
            newLineRecord.commitLine({sublistId:'recmachcustrecordcpqx_line_parent'});
        }
        console.log('['+script.getRemainingUsage()+']','About to save')
        newLineRecord.save({enableSourcing:true});
        console.log('['+script.getRemainingUsage()+']','New CPQ Line Created: '+newLineRecordId)
    });
```

I have confirmed in logging that the commodity field is set *before* the cost item.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring this question to NetSuite Support, it appears there is a defect.